# Wordpress Cron Job | Import

Tags: xml, wordpress, import, cron

Do you have any advice on how to create a cron which will allow me to do so?
I have an XML file that updates periodically with cars for sale. Simply put, if the car has been sold and is no longer available for purchase, it is no longer written to the XML file. To ensure that the car is no longer available on the site I created an ACF field that, if valued with a value greater than zero indicates that the car is available. If the custom field has a value less than one or is empty, this indicates that the car is no longer available.

Is there a way to get cron job to empty this ACF field as soon as the XML file no longer contains the car in question?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has its own cron system for scheduling tasks such as checking for updates, scheduling a post for publication, and deleting comments from the trash. All cron jobs are handled by WP-Cron.

On your case you can write a script or function that will run after a specific time with the help of the **WP-Cron** to check if the XML file no longer contains the car in question. Then it will empty the ACF field.

You can do it using a plugin called [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/). To know about the use of the plugin please check this [documentation](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/wordpress-cron-job/)

Comment: The hosting of the website in question is siteground so I will use their crons that work properly. 
I would like help in writing that function to empty the acf field which time the auto is no longer in the XML file